# Why detected language result is null in Java

Tags: java, locale

I'm trying to get the language format in Windows, but when I change the display format to `English (United States)` or `English (United Kingdom)` the returned value from `System.getProperty()` is `null`. For languages other than English, I get the correct result.

I'm using following code:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.language.format"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.country.format"));
```

Comment: how did you change the language?

Comment: If you're changing the language at runtime, there will be no effect on system properties, which are loaded at start up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The system properties and any properties in java are loaded at the start of your java application.

so java will load the properties and put them in the hashtable with key value form.

if you do a language format property call, it will take the language of the system and look for it in the hash table.

if you change the properties after running your application it will not find them and will return null.

that's it.